# Replacing path name in output file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace, tkinter, get

I need a Python code which replaces the place holders ('%p%') in a text template which is imported via

```
text_in = open(self.filename1, 'r')
```

and writing the path name which come from a input via tkinter with
tkFileDialog.askopenfilename. The template is completely read in. By writing a text file, the place holder should be replaced by the path name which is saved in the variable

```
self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename
```

I have tried it with the get() method like

```
replacements = {'%p%':self.filelocation.get(),'%r%':self.filelocation1.get()}
for line in text_in:
 for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
   line = line.replace(src, target)
 text_out.write(line)
text_in.close()
```

but it does not work like expected. My question is, when the text file is read an saved temporary and written into a text file, can the content by manipulated using the get() method or do I need the file names that I want to replace already hardcoded? I hope anybody has any ideas.

Comment: What are you doing with `text_out` after it's finished writing?

Comment: Actually it's not a textfile, I have just mentioned it, not to make it to complicated. It's a Safe Software FME Workspace that should be executed at the end with the dynamic path names I get via tkinter.

Comment: I have no idea what a _Safe Software FME Workspace_ is.  Does it rename `text_out` to `text_in`?

Comment: Thanks, this is a mistake. It should be `text_out.write(line) text_out.close()`

Comment: what is `self.filelocation` and `self.filelocation1`?  What does "does not work as expected" mean? Does it crash? Do you get an error? Are the wrong values substituted? Also, when you say "can the content be manipulated using the get() method..." -- what "get()" method are you talking about?

Comment: The main question is, if it's possible to use the replace and the get() method at the same time in this context. Replacing the place holder by the input path names and writing the content in a file.

Comment: Path names are saved in the variables self.filelocation and self.filelocation1 using tkinter (tkFileDialog.askopenfilename). It doesn't replace the variables with the saved path names. The .get() method (self.filelocation1.get()) is a method to replace parts of a template by dynamic text parts like path names or file names.

Comment: As far as I can tell this code should work, if you rename the new file to the original filename afterward.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the `get()` methods?  Do `self.filelocation.get()` and `self.filelocation1.get()` return the expected replacement text?

Comment: I don't get the output file as expected with the path names provided by tkinter. I don't know if the python code `replacements = {'%p%':self.filelocation.get(),'%r%':self.filelocation1.get()}` is the correct possibility to replace the '%p%' with the content of self.filelocation.get(). Maybe there is missing a step to save the content of 'self.filelocation.get()' in another variable and the replace the '%p%' before writing it into a new file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how you are defining `replacements` ,assuming that `self.filelocation.get()` returns a string.